# Is it possible to create a private stored proc in Firebird?

Tags: sql, firebird, encapsulation

I know I can set permissions on stored procs so that only certain users can call them.  But is there any way to mark a procedure as "private" (in the encapsulation sense) so that no user can call it directly, but it can still be called by other procedures called by a user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Firebird 3 (in development), you can have packaged-private procedures and functions.

Answer (score 0):

You may play with access rights.
Just can allow execution of "private" procedure just by specified procedure, user or role.